# Issues with AWK scripting for HTML tags

Tags: shell, awk

Below is the data file(results) contents-

```
13450708,13470474,US,15

24954,24845,JPN,44

14258992,14365059,US,4

24954,24845,IND,44
```

---

I want to send above data sets to email in a tabular format. For that I am using below awk script.
Now the challenge I am facing here is - I want to make the background color as red if the lastfield in the datasets ( i.e. here 15,44,4,44) > 40.
Can you please tell me how to use the same in below code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{

FS=","

print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>Store_count</TH><TH>Store_sold</TH><TH>Store_code</TH><TH>Backlogs</TH>"

}

 {

printf "<TR>"

for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i

print "</TR>"

 }

END{

print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"

 }

' results > file1.html
```

Comment: Google something like "set background color for html table cells" I guess. Did you try that?

Comment: I could see something from below link as well.

Comment: http://itwebtutorials.mga.edu/html/chp8/table-colors-and-backgrounds.aspx

Comment: However the issue here is how to extract the field from my awk script then do some checks then set background as red.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest here.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for help with. You already know how to use fields in awk since your script does that, and you apparently already know the HTML to set a cell background color so what exactly is it you need help with?

Comment: d I am not very sure how I will do fields check inside my begin end block. Can you please help me how I can write the same.

Comment: Can anyone please help here. I m not sure whether I can use if clause inside for loop in awk script. Please help me with the syntax

Comment: `I m not sure whether I can use if clause inside for loop` - why not try it? It'd take you about 1 minute to find out for yourself. There's nothing unusual about awk syntax. It's just like C or any other Algol-based language but with an implicit `while read` lop and `if condition do actions` evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why you're struggling with this since you seem to already have all of the information to do what you want, but anyway - just change:

```
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
```

to

```
printf "<TD%s>%s</TD>", ( (i==NF) && ($i > 40) ? " style=\"background-color:red\"" : "" ), $i
```

or if you don't like ternary expressions:

```
printf "<TD"
if ( (i==NF) && ($i > 40) ) {
    printf " style=\"background-color:red\""
}
printf ">%s</TD>, $i
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks Ed four suggestion. Based on my requirement where I need to check 4th field whether that's > 44 or not, I modify the code but still its not working.printf "<TD%s>%s</TD>", ($4 > 40 ? " style=\"background-color:red\"" : ""), $i

Comment: Can anyone please suggest here

Comment: Tell us in what way it's "not working" so we can help you figure out what is causing it to be "not working".

Comment: The initial requirement was to check the last field( $4) if > 40 or not , if > 40 then make background color as red. So if I will use the above code , all the lines are converted to red irrespective of condition. can you please rewrite my code if $4 > 40 condition.

Answer (score -1):

Anyways realized where I did the mistake anyways for me below code is giving results as expected. 
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

if (i ==4 && $4 >= 40)

{

printf "%s", $i

}

else

{

printf "%s", $i

}

print ""

}

END{

print ""

}

' results1 > file1.html