# AWK script to verify line number with field

Tags: shell, awk

I have below `awk` scripting which is to send email in a tabular format. The input to the `awk` script is a pipe delimited file.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{ 
FS="|"
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>Expected_code</TH><TH>Expected_Values</TH>"
}

{
  printf "<TR>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
  print "</TR>"
}

END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"}
' query_results > file.html
```

Contents of the pipe delimited file:

```
ABC|500
XYZ|300
TET|200
SCT|10
ASA|csr
```

Looking at the above datasets I need to change the `awk` script in such a way that

1. Every time it will check line number `4` and 2nd field ( here it's
   `10`) `> 0` or not , if its `> 0` then change the background color as red.
2. Every time it will check line number `5` and 2nd field ( here it's
   `csr`) is a not null field or not. If its a not null field then change the background color as red.

Comment: Hi Cyrus I think now it's look okay. Can u please  confirm

Comment: You can access the 2nd field with `$2` and use it in conditions. AWK supports some simple numeric and string operations with a syntax similar to C. E.g. `if ($2 == 10) { }` checks whether 2nd field contains `10`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567283/1745001, we just can't close it as such yet since the answer in the earlier question has no upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this way? :

```
awk -v RS="[|\n]" -v ORS="" '
BEGIN{print "<HTML><TABLE border=\"1\"><TH>Expected_code</TH><TH>Expected_Values</TH>\n"}
NR % 2{print "<TR><TD>" $0 "</TD>"}
!(NR%2){t="<TD>";if(( (NR == 8 || NR == 26) && $0 > 0) || ( (NR == 10 || NR == 28) && $0 != null) )t="<TD bgcolor=\"#FF0000\">"
print t $0 "</TD></TR>\n"}
END{print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"}'  query_results > outputfile;
```

With this way I just tried to avoid `for` sentence.

Comment: Thanks Gioconda for your suggestion. As per my question I need to check line number 13 and 2nd field > 0 and line number 14 is not null or not by below if clause condition, but its not giving correct result.if((NR == 13 && $0 > 0) || (NR == 14 && $0 != null)

Comment: The first condition needs to be in `NR % 2` and the second in `!(NR%2)`

Comment: Yeah I did the same thing.. However everytime only line number 8 with 2nd field is getting red if its > 0.. Its not checking for line number 13 and 14. Could u please rewrite your code.

Comment: Line number 14, in second field too?

Comment: I just update the code, you must change your question with that new constraints.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gioconda. Now infact I understood script completely .So much helpful. Just for my curiosity asking you cant we make such thing in for loop which I created in my question.

Comment: You're Welcome!. It's possible(write script with `for` loop)  I do in that way just to write less code. Remember that if you find this answer correct, mark it as that.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567283/1745001, we just can't close it as such yet since the answer in the earlier question has no upvotes.

Comment: May be content wise there is similarity but this is different than link. Anyways both are resolved .

Comment: John, Up-vote doesn't mean that the answer is solved, it is when you mark it as solved.

Comment: @John no, it's almost identical to the link. The difference is in comparing x vs y to generate red instead of comparing a vs b to generate red, i.e completely inconsequential and if you can't figure out one from the other then there is a bigger problem to address. The  code in your question even contains the same oddities (e.g. `""` mid-string for no reason) and bugs (e.g. `</BODY>` with no `<BODY>`) as the one in the other question so please don't even pretend it's not you again using a different login.

Comment: @EdMorton I am not pretending , I am not sure about the other question which was asked in another link.

Comment: @Gioconda can u please help me if we find the answer what need to be done.

Comment: OK, hopefully you can see why, given 2 different questions about changing a table cells background to red with exactly the same awk script posted in each question, I might think that they might be related.